# Giving pyodbc.Error while Dockerizing a Python API/Flask APP

Tags: python, docker, flask, odbc, pyodbc

I create a Python Flask API,but when I tried to build a docker image,It builds successfully,then when I tried to run the docker image,It also runs fine.But then,when I wanted to test the API,but hitting the API,It gives error,such as this..

```
 ' conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
    pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)") '
```

for your information,the dockerfile of mine is:

```
FROM python:3.6

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/

RUN bash odbc.sh
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 6000

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "dup_invoice_new.py" ]
```

and the odbc.sh file is-

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.list
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev unixodbc
apt-get -y update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev unixodbc 
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

The app is running in a server.Please let me know how can I remove this error and dockerize my app successfully.

for further info,dbconnection is done by the dbconn function-

```
def dbconnection(supp_inv_date):

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    filename='myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')

    # logging.info('Input request is : %s',js)

    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                          r'SERVER=<>.database.windows.net;'
                          r'DATABASE=<>;'
                          r'UID=<>;'
                          r'PWD=<>;')

    query = ""

    return conn,query
```

and this is my flask api structure-

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():

    js = request.json
    res = {<>}

    response = {'dupes': res}

    return json.dumps(response) 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(host='localhost', port='6000', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

The error is giving when I hit the app.run function.

Comment: Are you following [this](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows) ?

Comment: Hi,I had gone through the link.and also I trie dto use driver 17,but same error is giving.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that odbc.sh correctly set's up the environment?

try running:

```
docker exec <container-name> env
```

and check if your $PATH is set correctly. I'm unfamilar with ODBC, but the environment setup part jumped at me. If the python ODBC library depends on certain binary being present in the $PATH, then this could be what's causing your problem.